# How do I escape #{ from string interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interpolation

I have a heredoc where I am using `#{}` to interpolate some other strings, but there is an instance where I also want to write the actual text `#{some_ruby_stuff}` in my heredoc, WITHOUT it being interpolated. Is there a way to escape the #{.

I've tried "\", but no luck. Although it escapes the `#{}`, it also includes the "\":

```
>> <<-END
 #{RAILS_ENV} \#{RAILS_ENV} 
END
=> " development \#{RAILS_ENV}\n"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the backslash-hash is just Ruby being helpful in some irb-only way.

```
>> a,b = 1,2        #=> [1, 2]
>> s = "#{a} \#{b}" #=> "1 \#{b}"
>> puts s           #=> 1 #{b}
>> s.size           #=> 6
```

So I think you already have the correct answer.

Answer (score 21):

For heredoc without having to hand-escape all your potential interpolations, you can use single-quote-style-heredoc.  It works like this:

```
item = <<-'END'
  #{code} stuff
  whatever i want to say #{here}
END
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `'` quotes instead. Anything enclosed in them is not being interpolated.

Your solution with escaping `#` also works for me. Indeed Ruby interpreter shows

```
=> "\#{anything}"
```

but

```
> puts "\#{anything}"
#{anything}
=> nil
```

Your string includes exactly what you wanted, only `p` method shows it with escape characters. Actually, `p` method shows you, how string should be written to get exactly object represented by its parameter.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough - this is within a heredoc. I've updated the example to reflect that better.

Comment: the same still holds.  `"\#{anything}" == '#{anything}'`  No interpolation, and the generated string doesn't actually contain a backslash.  `irb` just displays one since it's using `String#inspect`.  Try `puts <<END` to see the (uninspected) string.