# Escape ruby string interpolation syntax

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I escape #{ from string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310701/how-do-i-escape-from-string-interpolation)

If I have a string like this:

```
"interpolated: #{1}, verbatim: #{dont_interpolate}"
```

How do I escape only the second #{} such that the output looks like this:

```
=> interpolated: 1, verbatim: #{dont_interpolate}
```

I tried this:

```
 "interpolated: #{1}, verbatim: #\{dont_interpolate\}"
```

but I get an extra slash in front of the #:

```
interpolated: 1, verbatim: \#{dont_interpolate}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I didn't see that one.

Comment: No problem, I wasn't quite sure if it would apply, because the solution was related to irb.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just pretty-printing the string in `irb`. When I use `puts`, it prints correctly:

```
irb(main):002:0> "interpolated: #{1}, verbatim: #\{dont_interpolate\}".to_s
=> "interpolated: 1, verbatim: \#{dont_interpolate}"
irb(main):003:0> puts "interpolated: #{1}, verbatim: #\{dont_interpolate\}"
interpolated: 1, verbatim: #{dont_interpolate}
=> nil
```

It seems you can also escape it this way:

```
irb(main):004:0> puts "interpolated: #{1}, verbatim: \#{dont_interpolate}"
interpolated: 1, verbatim: #{dont_interpolate}
=> nil
```