# Escape # in Rails link_to, Twitter Share link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, escaping, link-to

I'm trying to include an anchored article link in a Twitter share link dynamically with Rails `link_to` method:

```
<%= link_to "http://twitter.com/home?status=Check Out #{article.title} link.com/#{article.title.parameterize}" do %>
  <span class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></span>
<% end %>
```

The Twitter link share content outputs to:

> Check Out ARTICLE TITLE link.com/ARTICLE-TITLE.

The thing is I want to add a `#` character before ARTICLE-TITLE, as it is an anchor link in my view. I just can't seem to get the `#` to escape properly. Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape #{ from string interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310701/how-do-i-escape-from-string-interpolation)

Comment: @cantido I saw that answer and it's a little different. I basically want to add an additional '#' before '#{article.title}, but it doesn't seem to take. Thoughts?

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried `"\##{article.title}"` and that worked in my IRB, does it work for you?

Comment: @cantido I've tried that, and for some reason, it doesn't render in the Twitter Share link. The output in twitter is: link.com/

Comment: @cantido it doesn't even render the #{article.title} when the \# is entered before like you suggested

Comment: That's very odd. I just spun up a Rails app and tried that link, and `"link.com/\##{myvar.parameterize}"` worked for me. gitastic's answer looks like a good alternative to escape characters. Unfortunately I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

%23 = # (in a Twitter share link).

ex. link.com/%23#{article.title.parameterize}

Looks like it's rendered as a hashtag (#thattookwaytoolongtofigureout #ihopethishelpssomeone)

Comment: I can confirm that Chrome replaces that character with a regular hashtag when it is in a URL string.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a bad idea to build URLs with string concatenation—*especially* when you need to do something like put a URL in a query parameter of another URL.

To create correctly-encoded query parameters, use Rails' handy `Hash#to_query` method.

Let's take it from the inside out.

```
# Build the article URL
article_base_url = 'http://example.com/path'
article_url_hash = article.title.parameterize # => "my-article"
article_url = "#{article_base_url}##{article_url_hash}"
# => "http://example.com/path#my-article"

# Next, build the query string for the tweet URL
tweet_url_query = {
  status: "Check out #{article.title} #{article_url}"
}.to_query
# => "status=Check%20out%20My%20Article%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpath%23my-article"

# Finally, build the tweet URL:
base_tweet_url = 'https://twitter.com/home'
tweet_url = "#{base_tweet_url}?#{tweet_url_query}"
# => "https://twitter.com/home?status=Check%20out%20My%20Article%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpath%23my-article"
```

```
<%= link_to tweet_url do %>
  <span class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></span>
<% end %>
```

As perhaps you've already guessed, it's probably best to put this all in a helper:

```
ARTICLE_BASE_URL = 'http://example.com/'
TWEET_BASE_URL = 'http://twitter.com/home'

def tweet_url(title) 
  query = { status: tweet_text(title) }.to_query
  "#{TWEET_BASE_URL}?#{query}"
end

def tweet_text(title)
  "Check out #{title} #{article_url(title)}"
end

def article_url(title)
  "#{ARTICLE_BASE_URL}##{title.parameterize}"
end
```

```
<%= link_to tweet_url(article.title) do %>
  <span class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></span>
<% end %>
```

(You could, of course, reduce the above to a single two-line helper at the expense of readability and testability, but it would be a mistake.)